# How many times should a URL-as-a-value-in-a-querystring should be encoded?

Tags: javascript, urlencode, httpserver

I'm really confused how many times should I encode a URL when it is set as a value in a querystring 'coz we know browser has their own encoding process. Here's the scenario:

- I want to redirect to another location which I want to pass the previous URL:
  Note: the current URL is `http://localhost:8081/CostMonitoring/MainMenu.aspx?Option=AllCE`

Method A (without `encodeURIComponent()`):

```
window.location = 'CostEstimateApproval.aspx?CEMID=40' + 
        '&ToStatus=1CE'+
        '&PrevURL=' + window.location;
```

I get this in the address bar

```
http://localhost:8081/CostMonitoring/CostEstimateApproval.aspx?CEMID=40&ToStatus=1CE&PrevURL=http://localhost:8081/CostMonitoring/MainMenu.aspx?Option=AllCE
```

without `encodeURIComponent()`, everything works fine and the value of `Request.Querystring("PrevURL")` in the receiving page is

```
http://localhost:8081/CostMonitoring/MainMenu.aspx?Option=AllCE
```

which is correct.

Method B (with `encodeURIComponent()`):

```
window.location = 'CostEstimateApproval.aspx?CEMID=40' + 
        '&ToStatus=1CE'+
        '&PrevURL=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location);
```

with this method I get this in the address bar:

```
http://localhost:8081/CostMonitoring/CostEstimateApproval.aspx?CEMID=40&ToStatus=1CE&PrevURL=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8081%2FCostMonitoring%2FMainMenu.aspx%3FOption%3DAllCE
```

and the value of `Request.Querystring("PrevURL")` in the receiving page is

```
http://localhost:8081/CostMonitoring/MainMenu.aspx?Option=AllCE
```

which is also decoded correctly.

My questions:

1. Should I encode the URL-as-value? Will it be redundant if I encode it then the browser encode it again?
2. or should I let the browser encode it for me? If I let the browser, will the receiving page be confused from URL-as-a-value's value to the real URL value? Please consider this example:

   `http://www.domain.com/newpage.aspx?SameName=DifferentValue&PrevURL=http://www.domain.com/oldpage.aspx?SameName=DifferentValue&PrevURL=http://www.domain.com/anypage.aspx`

as you can see, both URL (the real URL and the URL-as-a-value) when not encoded has the same data name which is `SameName`. How does the receiving side handle this? or the HTTP server?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `encodeURIComponent` (once), since you're encoding a url parameter.

As you noted at the end of your question, failing to encode the url with `encodeURIComponent` would be problematic if your url included an `&`, for example.

Note that your Method A only worked because your example `prevUrl` is somewhat simply formed, e.g. it doesn't include a second url parameter.

Comment: I think you're right, when I paste `http://localhost:8081/CostMonitoring/Default.aspx?SameName=FromOrigURL&PrevURL=http://localhost:8081/CostMonitoring/Default.aspx?SameName=FromValueURL&PrevURL=http://localhost:8081/` in my address bar, and print the value of `SameName` and `PrevURL` in the receiving page, it gives me `FromOrigURL` for `SameName` and `http://localhost:8081/CostMonitoring/Default.aspx?SameName=FromValueURL,http://localhost:8081/` for the `PrevURL`, two `PrevURL` was considered.